# How can I get/pass the string from HTML file to Views file in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I've some strings/text in an HTML file. I want a new page when I click on them and individual string to give different view. How can I get the text/string from HTML to a Django view so that I can use them?

first_key is zip file so I'm lopping through two list items ad getting those list items as strings/text to print on one of my page. Upon clicking them I want a new page which I'm getting but unable to get the string/text/item value on which I clicked. I want the value '{{i}}' in my views. I've tried 
request.POST.get['mytext'] 
but all I'm getting is NONE. I want '{{i}}' stored in a variable in my views.py file.

```
{% for i,j in first_key %}
<tr>    
<td><a name="my_text" href = "{% url 'search_app:page'%}" >{{i}}</a></td>
<td>{{ j }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You want to send {{i}} and search for it right?

Comment: Your view (with url pattern "search_app:page") should take the value as argument, so you need to change your url pattern for search_app:page (e.g. if it is /page, change it to /page/<int:key>. Then your view function can be `def my_view(request, key)` where `key` is the parameter in the url. The template would then use `{% url 'search_app:page' key=i %}`

Comment: Do the django tutorial, you will learn how to do exactly that (selecting a poll question): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: Thanks a lot @dirkgroten it worked. Just a little correction there... it was showing couldn't find path (?P<key>[0-9]+$) so I changed my URL to something like page/(?P<key>[\w+]+) and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I found the answer and I'm posting it for others. @dirkgroten helped me in finding it out.

First of all I passed the value from href in anchor tag itself through URL something like `"{% url 'my_app:page' key=i %}"`

then in my urls.py file I changed the path from `page_view/` to `page_view/?P<key>[\w+]+`

and lastly in my views.py file I pass the key-value as an argument in the function something like `def page(request, key):` 
and then I was able to use the value of key in one of my views.

Answer (score 0):

get value of i from i =  `request.POST.get['my_text']` according to your code

```
 <td><a name="my_text" href = "{% url 'search_app:page'%}" >{{i}}</a></td>
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't worked. Check out my answer for the solution